# Cycle detection with recursive subquery factoring

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, hierarchical-query

Oracle SQL can do hierarchical queries since v2, using their proprietary CONNECT BY syntax. In their latest 11g release 2, they added recursive subquery factoring, also known as the recursive with clause. This is the ANSI standard, and if I understand correctly, this one has been implemented by other RDBMS vendors as well.

When comparing the connect-by with the recursive with, I noticed a difference in the result set when using cycle detection. The connect by results are more intuitive to me, so I'm wondering if Oracle's implementation contains a bug, or if this is standard ANSI and expected behaviour. Therefore my question is if you can check the recursive with query using other databases like MySQL, DB2, SQL Server and others. Provided those databases support the recursive with clause of course.

Here is how it works on Oracle 11.2.0.1.0

```
SQL> select *
  2    from t
  3  /

        ID  PARENT_ID
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          1

2 rows selected.
```

The query using CONNECT BY syntax:

```
SQL>  select id
  2        , parent_id
  3        , connect_by_iscycle
  4     from t
  5  connect by nocycle parent_id = prior id
  6    start with id = 1
  7  /

        ID  PARENT_ID CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE
---------- ---------- ------------------
         1          2                  0
         2          1                  1

2 rows selected.
```

Which looks intuitive to me. However, using the new ANSI syntax it returns one more row:

```
SQL> with tr (id,parent_id) as
  2  ( select id
  3         , parent_id
  4      from t
  5     where id = 1
  6     union all
  7    select t.id
  8         , t.parent_id
  9      from t
 10           join tr on t.parent_id = tr.id
 11  ) cycle id set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
 12  select id
 13       , parent_id
 14       , is_cycle
 15    from tr
 16  /

        ID  PARENT_ID I
---------- ---------- -
         1          2 0
         2          1 0
         1          2 1

3 rows selected.
```

This is the script you can use to check:

```
create table t
( id        number
, parent_id number
);
insert into t values (1, 2);
insert into t values (2, 1);
commit;
with tr (id,parent_id) as
( select id
       , parent_id
    from t
   where id = 1
   union all
  select t.id
       , t.parent_id
    from t
         join tr on t.parent_id = tr.id
) cycle id set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
select id
     , parent_id
     , is_cycle
  from tr;
```

Comment: The only DBs I'm aware of that support the `WITH` clause are Oracle 9i+, SQL Server 2005+, and DB2 (dunno version).  MySQL definitely does not support the `WITH` clause - the request has been in since 2006 :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From documentation on [`CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/pseudocolumns001.htm):

> The `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE` pseudocolumn returns `1` if the current row has a child which is also its ancestor

and that on [`CYCLE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm#BABFFJFD):

> A row is considered to form a cycle if one of its ancestor rows has the same values for the cycle columns.

In your example, row `2` does have a child which is also its ancestor, but its `id` has not been returned yet.

In other words, `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE` checks the **children** (which are yet to be returned), while `CYCLE` checks the **current row** (which is already returned).

`CONNECT BY` is row based, while recursive `CTE`'s are set-based.

Note that Oracle's documentation on `CYCLE` mentions an "ancestor row". However, generally speaking, there is no concept of an "ancestor row" in a recursive `CTE`. It's a set based operation which can yield results completely out of the tree. Generally speaking, the anchor part and the recursive part can even use the different tables.

Since recursive `CTE`'s are *usually* used to build hierarchy trees, `Oracle` decided to add a cycle check. But due the set-based way the recursive `CTE`'s operate, it's generally impossible to tell will the next step generate a cycle or not, because without a clear definition of the "ancestor row" cycle condition cannot be defined either.

To perform the "next" step, the whole "current" set needs to be available, but to generate each row of the current set (which includes the cycle column) we just need to have the results of the "next" operation.

It's not a problem if the current set always consists of a single row (like in `CONNECT BY`), but it is a problem if the recursive operation defined on a set as a whole.

Didn't look into `Oracle 11` yet, but `SQL Server` implements recursive `CTE`'s by just hiding a `CONNECT BY` behind them, which requires placing numerous restrictions (all of which effectively forbid all set-based operations).

`PostgreSQL`'s implementation, on the other hand, is truly set-based: you can do any operation with the anchor part in the recursive part. It does not have any means to detect cycles, though, because cycles are not defined in the first place.

As was mentioned before, `MySQL` does not implement `CTE`'s at all (it does not implement `HASH JOIN`'s or `MERGE JOIN`s as well, only the nested loops, so don't be surprised much).

Ironically, I received a letter today on this very subject, which I will cover in my blog.

**Update:**

Recursive `CTE`'s in `SQL Server` are no more than `CONNECT BY` in disguise. See this article in my blog for shocking details:

- [**SQL Server: are the recursive CTE’s really set-based?**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/18/sql-server-are-the-recursive-ctes-really-set-based/)

Comment: Good explanation, Quassnoi. Thanks. So the recursive with clause works as expected. It's just different than the connect-by. It's nice to be aware of these little nuances between the two.

Comment: This explanation is nice, but I believe it is incorrect. Specifically, what is not clear is the definition of "ancestor". If the definition was set-based as you suggest, then we should detect a cycle with the following data and recursive query. Yet if you look at the output, `CYCLE` is 0 in all rows. If your explanation was correct, one of the (1, 3) rows should have `CYCLE = 1` - indeed, the values in both columns are the same, and one row is generated in the anchor member while the other is from the recursive member. One is the ancestor of the other, if the definition was **set** based.

Comment: `with
  t(parent, child) as (
    select 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 1, 3 from dual union all
    select 2, 3 from dual
  ),
  r (parent, child) as (
    select parent, child from t where parent = 1
    union all
    select r.parent, t.child from t join r on t.parent = r.child
  )
  cycle parent, child set cycle to '1' default '0'
select * from r;`

Comment: @mathguy: I explicitly mentioned that yes, it's not clear, and no, I "didn't look into Oracle 11 yet" in the post. Oracle requires that *the recursive member must follow the anchor member and must reference `query_name` exactly once*. I don't have an installation handy, but I believe the other limitations, which effectively make the recursive CTE row-based, do apply as well. If you define the cycle column explicitly like you do in your example, Oracle uses it; if you don't, it uses the subset of the anchor part columns used in the join to the recursive part.

Comment: @mathguy: PostgreSQL, as I said, does not have a built-in cycle detector, does not limit the recursive CTE complexity in any way and does not have any objections against running infinite recursions

Comment: Your explanation seemed to be specifically about Oracle implementations. You quote Oracle documentation and compare to Oracle `CONNECT BY`. At least for Oracle, the explanation is nice but incorrect. Another example to consider: `with r(x) as (select 0 from dual union all select x+1 from r) select * from r` throws the `cycle detected` error. Here a cycle is detected, but not based on "equal values" in **any** set of columns involved in the recursive CTE: there is only one column and there are no repeated values.

Comment: I understand you don't have an Oracle db to test, but that fact doesn't somehow make the answer correct. Cycles, at least in the Oracle implementation, don't seem to have anything to do with "set based" ancestry, and - contrary to the Oracle documentation - don't always seem to be defined exclusively in terms of "repeating values" in a set of columns, as they are for `CONNECT BY` queries.

Comment: @mathguy: I might not have been clear in my post. What I meant to say is that Oracle's definition of `CYCLE` refers to a concept of "ancestor row" which is not clearly defined for a recursive CTE. I then mentioned that PostgreSQL does not use this concept at all; SQL Server (poorly) limits its anchor part to operations which are distributive over multiset addition (`UNION ALL`); and as for Oracle, I don't know. Could you please cite the exact sentence from my answer which you believe is not correct so that I could make it more clear? Thank you!

Comment: @mathguy: in your previous example, the subset of columns used in the join is the empty set, and the 0-tuple is used for cycle detection, which is of course the same for all rows. The way I see it it's not contrary to the documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187453/discussion-between-mathguy-and-quassnoi).

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL supports WITH-style hierarchical queries, but doesn't have any automatic cycle detection. This means that you need to write your own and the number of rows returned depends on the way you specify join conditions in the recursive part of the query.

Both examples use an array if IDs (called all_ids) to detect loops:

```
WITH recursive tr (id, parent_id, all_ids, cycle) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, ARRAY[id], false
    FROM t
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, all_ids || t.id, t.id = ANY(all_ids)
    FROM t
    JOIN tr ON t.parent_id = tr.id AND NOT cycle)
SELECT id, parent_id, cycle
FROM tr;

 id | parent_id | cycle
----+-----------+-------
  1 |         2 | f
  2 |         1 | f
  1 |         2 | t


WITH recursive tr (id, parent_id, all_ids, cycle) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, ARRAY[id], false
    FROM t
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, all_ids || t.id, (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t AS x WHERE x.id = t.parent_id))
    FROM t
    JOIN tr ON t.parent_id = tr.id
    WHERE NOT t.id = ANY(all_ids))
SELECT id, parent_id, cycle
FROM tr;

 id | parent_id | cycle
----+-----------+-------
  1 |         2 | f
  2 |         1 | t
```

Comment: Very interesting queries. Oracle doesn't support that array syntax, but it's nice to see that the results are the same as in Oracle's ANSI syntax. It leads me to think that the ANSI query maybe doesn't contain a bug after all. Thanks, Aleksander.

Comment: Late to the party, but nowadays PostgreSQL also allows you to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to remove cycles automatically.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK:

- MySQL doesn't support recursive CTE's
- SQL Sever does not support cycle
  detection in recursive CTE's

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTEs at all.

Comment: That's clear, thanks. So MySQL and SQL Server cannot be used to test this script.

Comment: Indeed, MS SQL Server has a maximum recursion limit, something like 100 by default.

Answer (score 2):

Results of the connect by may not always be intuitive.

Below queries demonstrate different approaches to detect cycles starting with `id = 3` for the graph on the picture.

```
create table graph (id, id_parent) as
(select 2, 1 from dual
union all select 3, 1 from dual
union all select 4, 3 from dual
union all select 5, 4 from dual
union all select 3, 5 from dual)
```

[image]

```
SQL> select level lvl, graph.*, connect_by_iscycle cycle
  2    from graph
  3   start with id = 3
  4  connect by nocycle prior id = id_parent;

       LVL         ID  ID_PARENT      CYCLE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          1          0
         2          4          3          0
         3          5          4          1
         1          3          5          0
         2          4          3          0
         3          5          4          1

6 rows selected.

SQL> select level lvl, graph.*, connect_by_iscycle cycle
  2    from graph
  3   start with id = 3
  4  connect by nocycle prior id = id_parent
  5         and prior id_parent is not null;

       LVL         ID  ID_PARENT      CYCLE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          1          0
         2          4          3          0
         3          5          4          0
         4          3          5          1
         1          3          5          0
         2          4          3          0
         3          5          4          1

7 rows selected.

SQL> with t(id, id_parent) as
  2   (select *
  3      from graph
  4     where id = 3
  5    union all
  6    select g.id, g.id_parent
  7      from t
  8      join graph g
  9        on t.id = g.id_parent)
 10  search depth first by id set ord
 11  cycle id set cycle to 1 default 0
 12  select * from t;

        ID  ID_PARENT        ORD C
---------- ---------- ---------- -
         3          1          1 0
         4          3          2 0
         5          4          3 0
         3          5          4 1
         3          5          5 0
         4          3          6 0
         5          4          7 0
         3          5          8 1

8 rows selected.
```

Node with `id = 3` has two parents so Oracle traverses two cycles in this example.

```
(1, 3) -> (3, 4) -> (4, 5) -> (5, 3)
```

and

```
(5, 3) -> (3, 4) -> (4, 5)
```

Edge (5, 3) is missing from the result of the first query and first cycle.
At the same time edge (5, 3) appears in the result for the third query and second cycle twice.

Why so? You can check description of the cycle detection logic in the answer provided by Quassnoi. In plain English it means that

> (1) connect by detects a cycle if **child ID for current row** is part of
>   IDs visited so far
>
> (2) rec with detects a cycle if **ID for current row** is part of IDs
>   visited so far

Result of the second query looks the most natural although there is additional predicate `and prior id_parent is not null`. In this case

> (3) it detects a cycle if **ID for current row** is part of **parent IDs**
>   visited so far

All this conditions are implemented in columns cnt1, cnt2, cnt3 in below query.

```
SQL> with t(id, id_parent, path_id, path_id_parent, cnt1, cnt2, cnt3) as
  2   (select g.*,
  3           cast('->' || g.id as varchar2(4000)),
  4           cast('->' || g.id_parent as varchar2(4000)),
  5           0,
  6           0,
  7           0
  8      from graph g
  9     where id = 3
 10    union all
 11    select g.id,
 12           g.id_parent,
 13           t.path_id || '->' || g.id,
 14           t.path_id_parent || '->' || g.id_parent,
 15           regexp_count(t.path_id || '->', '->' ||
 16            (select id from graph c where c.id_parent = g.id) || '->'),
 17           regexp_count(t.path_id || '->', '->' || g.id || '->'),
 18           regexp_count(t.path_id_parent || '->', '->' || g.id || '->')
 19      from t
 20      join graph g
 21        on t.id = g.id_parent
 22    -- and t.cnt1 = 0
 23    -- and t.cnt2 = 0
 24    -- and t.cnt3 = 0
 25    )
 26  search depth first by id set ord
 27  cycle id set cycle to 1 default 0
 28  select * from t;

        ID  ID_PARENT PATH_ID         PATH_ID_PARENT  CNT1 CNT2 CNT3        ORD C
---------- ---------- --------------- --------------- ---- ---- ---- ---------- -
         3          1 ->3             ->1                0    0    0          1 0
         4          3 ->3->4          ->1->3             0    0    0          2 0
         5          4 ->3->4->5       ->1->3->4          1    0    0          3 0
         3          5 ->3->4->5->3    ->1->3->4->5       1    1    1          4 1
         3          5 ->3             ->5                0    0    0          5 0
         4          3 ->3->4          ->5->3             0    0    0          6 0
         5          4 ->3->4->5       ->5->3->4          1    0    1          7 0
         3          5 ->3->4->5->3    ->5->3->4->5       1    1    1          8 1

8 rows selected.
```

If you uncomment filter by cnt1/cnt2/cnt3 and remove "cycle id set cycle to 1 default 0" then query will return result as corresponding query above. In other words **you can avoid `cycle clause` and implement whatever cycle detection logic you find more intuitive**.

Additional details about traversing hierarchies and cycle detection can be found in the book [Oracle SQL Revealed](https://www.apress.com/gb/book/9781484233719).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Server version 5.0.45 didn't like `with`:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'with tr (id, parent_id) as (select id, parent_id
>   from t where id = 1 union all s' at line 1.

Comment: Thanks for trying, wallyk. But does MySQL support something similar and this just isn't the right syntax, or doesn't MySQL doesn't support recursive queries at all?

Comment: I don't think it does.  It was only a few years ago that it did not support stored procedures, so it has evolved rather quickly.  I wouldn't be surprised if such things are in the latest version, or a upcoming version.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE s (master, slave, all_ids, cycle) AS
(
    SELECT master, slave, ARRAY[master], false FROM binding WHERE master=3477

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.master, d.slave, all_ids || d.master, d.slave = ANY(all_ids)
    FROM
        binding AS d
    JOIN
        s
    ON (d.master = s.slave)
    WHERE NOT d.master = ANY(all_ids)
)
SELECT *
FROM s;
```

I think better is this condition `d.slave = ANY(all_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

*"Therefore my question is if you can check the recursive with query using other databases like MySQL, DB2, SQL Server and others"*

MariaDB 10.5.2 and newer support cycle detection:

> [WITH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/)
>
> The CYCLE clause enables CTE cycle detection, avoiding excessive or infinite loops, MariaDB supports a relaxed, non-standard grammar.
>
> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE ... (
>  ...
> )
> CYCLE <cycle column list> RESTRICT
> ```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT, parent_id INT);
INSERT INTO t(id, parent_id) VALUES (1, NULL),(2,1),(3,2),(1,3);

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, 0 lvl 
  FROM t WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, lvl + 1 AS lvl
  FROM cte c1
  JOIN t ON c1.id = t.parent_id
)
CYCLE id, parent_id RESTRICT 
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY lvl;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=401ecaf984654be1f7c6fa588fbda843)**