# Cycle detection for recursive SQL WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

Let us assume that we have normal hierarchical table with `parent` column pointing to its parent. I wanted to build query that will enumerate all ancestors with SQL WITH clause.

```
with data_ancestors (par, chi) AS (
  SELECT d.parent, d.dat_id
    FROM data d
    WHERE d.parent IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL

  SELECT p.parent, a.chi
  FROM dta_ancestors a
  JOIN data p
  ON p.dat_id = a.par
  WHERE p.parent IS NOT NULL   
) 
select * from dta_ancestors where par  = 1 order by chi;
```

The problem here is that although the data should not contains cycles, it is not guaranteed so. In such wrong case I want to gradually degrade the functionality (loops should be arbitrary broken). However Oracle ends with error during execution on "wrong" data.

I know I can use different more Oracle specific approach like:

```
select p.dat_id, a.dat_id from data p, data a where a.dat_id in (
  select d.dat_id from data d start with d.dat_id = p.dat_id connect by nocycle prior d.dat_id = d.parent
);
```

or as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731889/cycle-detection-with-recursive-subquery-factoring) to make cycle detection by myself.

However are there any other nice solutions (mainly for Oracle but also other DBs) that solves the recursion problems with WITH clause?

Comment: The difficulty here is in determining what constitutes a 'cycle'.  You may have various legitimate entry points into the same hierarchy section, so exactly how would you determine a unique cycle from a hypothetical standpoint?

Comment: Did you notice the `is_cycle` part in the recursive CTE in that answer: `cycle id set is_cycle to '1' default '0'`; this is how you'd normally do it. What is incorrect about this?

Comment: @PinnyM : if we "see" the cycle there, I don't care where do I brake cycle (although there may be more possible solution to brake the cycle). I agree that it is problem for generic WITH syntax to define what cycle is. However Oracle somehow stops and reports the problem. In theory one acceptable "solution" from DB would be set-based termination when nothing more is added. However Oracle support just `UNION ALL`

Comment: @Ben : To be honest, I do notice `is_cycle` in question itself, but was not able to "use" it in my example. Just adding `cycle id set is_cycle to '1' default '0'` after closing ) ended in some SQL error (can't remember now, can try tomorrow when I will have access to DB). I thought that it is somehow connect to `connect by`. Can you give me the "working" example? :)