# How to extract values within an Oracle CLOB field and turn them into table rows?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, clob

Within my Oracle PL/SQL procedure, I am storing a stream of values within one CLOB field where the values are separated by a carriage return/line feed. The values within my CLOB field can vary in size.

An example stream of data that I might have might look like this:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
FFFF
```

As mentioned above, each line in this example is separated by a carriage return/line feed but is stored all within one CLOB field, i.e. ELEMENT which is of type CLOB.

What I would like is to be able to read this ELEMENT field, take each value, prior to each carriage return/line feed and insert it as one row into a database table, i.e:

```
MY_TABLE (ID NUMBER, MY_ELEMENT VARCHAR2(256))
```

So using the data above, I would like the following end result:

```
MY_TABLE:

1, AAAA
2, BBBB
3, CCCC
4, DDDD
5, EEEE
6, FFFF
```

The problem I am having is that I am unsure how to extract the values within my ELEMENT CLOB field and turn them into individual rows as described above.

Comment: Is there a max size for the clob?

Comment: I have not set the max size so the max size will be 4Gb.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a while loop reading the CLOB using the dbms_lob package and make chunks searching the return carriage chr(10). Example code:

```
PROCEDURE chopClob(l_clob CLOB) IS
offset number := 1;
ChunkSize number := 32767;
len    number := dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob);
l_buffer varchar2(32767);
i NUMBER := 1;
chunkSize NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  IF ( dbms_lob.isopen(l_clob) != 1 ) THEN
        dbms_lob.open(l_clob, 0);
  END IF;
  chunkSize := instr(l_clob, chr(10), offset);
  WHILE ( offset < len ) LOOP
        dbms_lob.read(l_clob, ChunkSize, offset, l_buffer);
        dbms_output.put_line('Line '||i||':'||l_buffer);
        /* Put your code here :) */
        offset := offset + ChunkSize;
        i := i + 1;
 END LOOP;

 IF ( dbms_lob.isopen(l_clob) = 1 ) then
        dbms_lob.close(l_clob);
 END IF; 
end chopClob;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that works in 11gR2 due to the recursive subquery factoring feature [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731889/cycle-detection-with-recursive-subquery-factoring), but I'm afraid I cannot explain it as I need to study it myself yet!  I was intrigued by the challenge and after finding Jack Douglas' post here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/oracle-read-from-clob-column-line-by-line-and-insert-to-the-table I tweaked it for your scenario.  Note that the line number of the CLOB data row becomes the ID in the new table.

Set up:

```
create table tbl_with_clob_col(id integer, element clob);
create table tbl_parsed(id integer, my_element varchar2(100));

insert into tbl_with_clob_col(id, element) values (1, 'AAAA'||chr(10)||'BBBB'||chr(10)||'CCCC');
```

Parse the CLOB data and insert it into a new table:

```
insert into tbl_parsed (
select line#, line from (
with w(id, line#, line, rest) as (
  select id, 1, regexp_substr(to_char(element), '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 
     substr(to_char(element), regexp_instr(element, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1)
  from tbl_with_clob_col
  union all
  select id, line#+1, regexp_substr(rest, '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 
     substr(rest, regexp_instr(rest, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1)
  from w
  where rest is not null ) cycle id, line# set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
select line#, line from w order by id, line#
));
```

Proof:

```
SQL> select * from tbl_parsed;

        ID MY_ELEMENT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 AAAA
         2 BBBB
         3 CCCC

3 rows selected.
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a159/1) example.

If you see any caveats please let us know.